# Why is my algorithm O(1) additional space complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, space-complexity

I solved this problem from codefights:

Note: Write a solution with O(n) time complexity and O(1) additional space complexity, since this is what you would be asked to do during a real interview.

Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to a.length, find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other number does. If there are no such elements, return -1.

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a) {
    HashSet z = new HashSet();
    for (int i: a) {
        if (z.contains(i)){
            return i;
        }
        z.add(i);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

My solution passed all of the tests. However I don't understand how my solution met the O(1) additional space complexity requirement. The size of the hashtable is directly proportional to the input so I would think it is O(n) space complexity. Did codefights incorrectly test my algorithm or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: In my experience space constraints are usually tested by online judges. They are mostly just there so you know that in an actual interview, you might have be asked to do it that way. You're right, your algorithm clearly doesn't use constant additional space.

Comment: `only numbers in the range from 1 to a.length` - could you clarify that please?

Comment: @xenteros what is unclear about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn’t have O(1) auxiliary space complexity, since that hash set can grow up to size n if given an array of all different elements.

My guess is that the online testing infrastructure didn’t check memory usage or otherwise checked memory usage incorrectly. If you want to meet the space constraints, you’ll need to go back and try solving the problem a different way.

As a hint, think about reordering the array elements.

Comment: isn't the auxiliary space O(1) because it doesn't use any space beyond the input size?

Comment: @LazerStackr Typically, auxiliary space measures all of the memory used by the algorithm except for the memory used by the arguments themselves. Since the memory in the `HashSet` isn't part of the original array (though the values in that `HashSet` are taken from the original array), this wouldn't be considered O(1) space.

Comment: So how can you manipulate the elements without copying it into a data structure that doesn't use more than O(1) extra space ?

Comment: You could use an in place soring algorithm such as Insertion Sort to maintain O(1) space complexity but that would bust the O(n) time complexity requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are able to modify incomming array, you could fix your problem with `O(n)` time complexity, and *do not use external memory*.

```
public static int getFirstDuplicate(int... arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int val = Math.abs(arr[i]);

        if (arr[val - 1] < 0)
            return val;
        arr[val - 1] = -arr[val - 1];
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This solution is O(n) space as well.

Comment: @xenteros yes, I moved my first example back. I am thinking about using this approach to find all unique duplicates, but is seems it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically incorrect, for two reasons.

Firstly, depending on the values in the array, there may be overhead when the `int`s become `Integer`s and added to the `HashSet`.

Secondly, while the additional memory is largely the overhead associated with a `HashSet`, that overhead is linearly proportional to the size of the set.  (Note that I am not counting the elements in this, as they are already present in the array.)

Usually, these memory constraints are tested by setting a limit to the amount of memory it can use.  A solution like this I would expect to fall below the said threshold.